# Multi column div inside table: Containing div only has width of the first columns

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to put a "div" around another div that may contain multiple columns.

However, as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b4fucp5x/)

```
<table class="datatable">
<tr>
   <td class="leftcolumn">Radiobuttons:</td>
   <td class="rightcolumn">
      <div style="border: 2px solid grey;">
         before
         <div class="morecols">
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="1" /> One</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="2" /> Two</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="3" /> Three</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="4"checked="checked" /> Four</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="5" /> Five</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="6" /> Six</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="7" /> Seven</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="8" /> Eight</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" name="ctypeid" value="9" /> Nine</label>
         </div>after
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the blue-colored div only is as wide as the first column. I'd like to contain all three of them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Give 100% width to table like this "<table class="datatable" width="100%">", It might help.

Comment: Check the [column-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-rule) property.

Answer (score 1):

```
.morecols { <br>
   height: 65px;
   -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
   border: 1px solid black;
   column-rule: 1px solid grey;
     background-color: #ccccff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alsida but I'd like rather not to know how many columns there will be, that's why I set the height...

Answer (score 0):

I've changed two things

## 1. 100% width to your table

```
<table class="datatable" width="100%">
```

## 2. Reduced width of '.morecols' class to 100px;

```
.morecols {
   height: 65px;
   -moz-columns: 100px;
   -webkit-columns: 100px;
   columns: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   column-rule: 1px solid grey;
     background-color: #ccccff;
}
```

Now it looks good.

Check updated fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/b4fucp5x/1/

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Kaushal but I would prefer the table to not be wider than necessary.. is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

So you don't know how many columns there will be and you don't want table to not be wider than necessary.

Okay to do so again I've done two things to your provided code

1. Removed `<br>` tag from the 'morecols' div.
2. Added float to the all labels and breaking the 3rd label float to fit it into your given height.

Here is a updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b4fucp5x/6/